# How to notify user that new channel needs to be opened using Pusher?

Tags: javascript, php, pusher

I use pusher to implement real-time chat and notifications in my website. Users are allowed to start conversation(chat) with others and conversation can be only 1 on 1.

Messages are also stored in db so that user could have chat history as well.

I user with userId=14 has three active conversation I would generate JS script in php that would connect him to pusher and subscribe for three presence-channels representing each of three conversations. Every channel has events like "new-msg" etc. Everything work great - users get message if chat window is open or notification badge if not.

The problem starts when another user want to start a new conversation with userId=14. There is no private or presence channel for that. If I used public channel then every logged in user would get notified which is not good.

What I do know is that once logged in my website users connect to pusher and additionally to already active presence-channels subsribe to public channel "new-conversations" but every user waits for specific event which represents his userId.

```
var pusher = new Pusher('APP_KEY');
var channel = pusher.subscribe('new-conversations');
channel.bind(userId,
  function(data) {
    // subscribes to new presence-channel using information from data variable
  }
);
```

When another user wants to start conversation with userId=14 he makes ajax call to server where PHP script generates event representing userId=14 containing data about himself and sends it to every connected(logged in) user but only userId=14 is waiting for this. Once triggered userId=14 can subsribe to new presence-channel.

While all this scenario works, I was wondering if there is some better, more cleaner out-of-the-box solution to this situation? I have read through pusher documentation but found nothing but I refuse to except that pusher developrs havent though about it.

**POSSIBLE SOLUTION**

I though of another solution. Every user should subscribe to presence-channel `var channel = pusher.subscribe('presence-14');` where 14 = userId. If userId= 39 wants to start conversation with him he would send userId=14 to server and server would send userId=39 to channel "presence-14". Is that it?

Comment: I suggest use WebSocket-HTML 5 rather than pushers.

Comment: This is something new for me. I did research but did not found this option. I prefered pusher over other options (basically just one - Ratchet - because I use PHP in server side) because as it is paid service it handles all the maintaince and errors, generally lot more safer for someone who is not profesional in websocket field.
Could you please provide some feedback on how easy and safe is to use WebSocket-HTML 5?